# Lightweight .Net CMS Library

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, content-management-system

I am looking for a lightweight CMS Library for a .net MVC application. I don't need any frontend management, just a library that can store and retrieve pieces of content. I plan on writing the frontend myself. The most complex thing I can see myself needing to store is a set of news posts. Aside from this I need to be able to store sets of arbitrary key value pairs for each page. Resource files probably provide the best model for this except that they are not editable and persistable during run time.

The closest thing I have found is [Eucalypto](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/eucalypto.aspx) which looks like it should fit the bill pretty well. I can rip out the forums and wiki easily enough as I don't need them. But it doesn't seem to have been developed for a while and I have heard nothing about it in the past and so would be worried about reliability. Any ideas of a library that might do this?

I am aware that it might be simpler to just roll my own SQL database for something this simple, but if a good library esists it could save me some time and trouble.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at a document database. [MindTouch's Dream](http://wiki.developer.mindtouch.com/Dream) comes to mind - it's the engine behind DekiWiki, and runs on Mono. I assume it'd also run on .NET with no (or minimal) changes.

Comment: This does looks promising from a design and api point of view. However it really doesn't fulfil my needs as far as ease of use is concerned. With no downloadable DLL and no documentation for running it simply as a DLL reference I am hesitant to deploy it as part of my application.

Comment: @JayArr - Agree it's not easy to find, but the Dream SDK and Src includes compilied binaries: http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=173074&package_id=198357 along with samples.

Answer (score -1):

Hi i saw Eucalypto too. but there are no web interface. It will be difficult if y are beginner in asp.net
Eucalypto does not have a good community.And it does not grow

Comment: What kind of answer is this? You are NOT recommending a product?

Answer (score -1):

I would recoment having a look at [n2](http://n2cms.com/). Contains most things you need for a normal site without being to bloated. The datalayer is based on NHiberbnate so you can use most relational databases. Works well with MVC aswell.

Answer (score -1):

I think [Kooboo](http://www.kooboo.com/) is the most simplest and extendable and robust CMS in the .NET Area (i don't like Orchard, it's extensible, but not robust, ).

Comment: Cannot tell anything about Kooboo 3.x, but Kooboo 1.x-2.x is good, but it's not lightweight.